# Pandas DataFrame to percent function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there any nice build in function in `pandas` which can convert values in DataFrame to percent (by rows, by columns or any more complex combination with use of levels)?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? For the whole DataFrame? One column? There aren’t any built-ins that do it automatically for either, but it is easy to implement your own as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure that is what you mean, but if you want to know the percentage value within the columns you can do it like this:

```
for col in df:
  df[col] = (df[col]/df[col].sum()) * 100
```